# Timespan problem

Tags: c#, timespan

i have write a small code which check on time routine if a zip file is older than 5 hours (300 mint) then the file must be deleted.
i have this code. but it is not deleting any file.

```
string[] zipfiles = Directory.GetFiles("D:\\images\\zipFiles\\", "*.zip*");

foreach (string zip in zipfiles)
{
    FileInfo zipinfo = new FileInfo(zip);
    string t = zipinfo.CreationTime.ToString();
    TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - zipinfo.CreationTime;
    int k =0;
    k = span.Minutes;
    if (k > 300)
    {
        zipinfo.Delete();
    }
    else
    { 

    }
}
```

Comment: Are there even files in that directory? Are they older then 5 hours? Does it throw an exception? Are the files in use?

Comment: @Bobby yes the file are older than 5 hours,and it does not throw any exception?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want [`TimeSpan.TotalMinutes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes.aspx).  The `Minutes` property only returns the minutes portion of the timespan (0-59).

Comment: @Talljoe, so then what i need to do, because i need to delete the file only if they are 5 hours old i.e three hundred minutes.

Comment: Where you have `span.Minutes` you need to put `span.TotalMinutes`.

Comment: yes i put  `total mintues` and also declare  `K as double` but still it is not working ?

Comment: Debug the program.  Put a breakpoint on that line.  See what the value of `TotalMinutes` is at that point.  Use that information to figure out the problem.

Comment: @Talljoe ok thanks but apparently there is nothing wrong with the logic and code, the way i am doing it right?

Answer (score 3):

The other answers about using `TotalMinutes` instead of `Minutes` are spot on, but since you also asked about the overall logic and code, I thought I might suggest an alternative:

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\images\\zipFiles\\");
var now = DateTime.Now;
var oldFiles = dir.GetFiles("*.zip")
                  .Where(f => (now - f.CreationTime).TotalMinutes > 300);
foreach (var file in oldFiles)
    file.Delete();
```

This does the exact same thing as your code, but in a more concise and (in my opinion) readable manner. Because it uses LINQ, you'd need at least .NET 3.5 to compile this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string[] zipfiles = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Delete\\New Folder\\", "*.cs*");

        foreach (string zip in zipfiles)
        {

            FileInfo zipinfo = new FileInfo(zip);
            string t = zipinfo.CreationTime.ToString();
            TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - zipinfo.CreationTime;
            double k = 0;
            k = span.TotalMinutes;
            if (k > 10)
            {

                zipinfo.Delete();
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
```

TotalMinutes gets the value of the whole and fractional minutes of the timespan

Comment: Please refrain from just Copy&Pasting a whole block of code without any hint to the fix, this is bad practice. Explain what the error is, what the solution is and give the example on how to fix it. We are here to help in finding solutions and to help to learn, we're not here to do all the work.

Comment: Will do so Bobby. Thanks for the Info

Comment: @Kishore Borra i have the same piece of code but it is not working, i have file there more than 5 hours old.but it is not deleting them.

Comment: the change is in the below lines as suggested by Bobby already.

Comment: double k = 0;
 k = span.TotalMinutes;

Comment: what is your operating system?

Comment: @Kishore Borra: From the question: `Directory.GetFiles("D:\\images\\zipFiles\\", "*.zip*");`. ;)